# which is better to return in a springMVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a springMVC controller,

which is better to return?

---

edit 1

- ModelAndView (Class)
- Model (Interface)
- Map
- String
- void
- View
- `HttpEntity<?>` or `ResponseEntity<?>`
- `HttpHeaders`

and much more.

Now, I know these return types has different meaning.

Like `String`, return a view name.

And, when I want return a view with some objects, `ModelAndView` is a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the big features Spring provides you is automatic conversion between formats, such as POJOs and JSON or XML. Don't reinvent the wheel--just return the POJO (or a `ResponseEntity<Pojo>` if needed). This makes your code much simpler, more reliable, and easier to test.